# Sublist based on Parent List

Tags: list

I have a parent SharePoint list that's comprised of resources specific to individual projects. So column A is the Resource and column B is the project the resource is assigned to and column C is details about the resource. Is there a way to create a child list which contains information in the parent but only for a specific project?